# How to remove old version of Java and install new version

Tags: java, linux

I have a Linux box on which Java 1.7 is installed:

```
#java -version
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

But for some new tool I need to install the [jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz)

So how can I remove old one and install the new one?

Comment: How did you install Java? Where? Try `which java`.

Comment: Which distribution do you use and how did you install java? via packaging manager or manually?

Comment: # which java
/usr/bin/java

I am not sure how the old one was deployed

Comment: How to install software is not a programming question.  Please read the Help Centre documentation on what to ask *before* you ask questions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. To remove OpenJDK (the one you've already installed)

   `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*`
2. Make a new directory for your new JDK

   `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java`
3. Copy the file to the directory (you should be in that file path)

   `sudo cp -r jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java/`
4. Extract the file

   `sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`
5. You should add this to your PATH now. To do that:

   a. Open /etc/profile : `sudo gedit /etc/profile`

   b. Scroll down (the end) and add the path where your jdk was installed

   `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45
   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   export JAVA_HOME
   export PATH`

   Save and exit
6. Inform your Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located.

   a. Notify the system that Oracle Java JRE is available for use

   `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" 1`

   b. Notify the system that Oracle Java JDK is available for use

   `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac" 1`

   c. Notify the system that Oracle Java Web start is available for use

   `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javaws" 1`
7. Inform your Linux system that Oracle Java JDK/JRE must be the default Java.

   a. Set the java runtime environment for the system

   `sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java`

   b. Set the javac compiler for the system

   `sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac`

   c. Set Java Web start for the system

   `sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javaws`
8. Reload your system wide PATH

   `source /etc/profile`
9. Check the new version and you're done!

   `java -version`

Comment: Awesome tutorial! I couldn't reload PATH but restart the machine, however it works like a charm

Answer (score 7):

Just unpack the new Java version, for example into `/opt`. Then do

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Put these `export`s into the startup files for your shell and you should be set. It is not necessary to uninstall the Java 7 installation.

Comment: if you have installed it using rpm package, then default location is /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_xx

Answer (score 6):

On Centos/Redhat

First do : `rpm -qa|grep jdk`
And then : `rpm -e <the version which you dont want>`

Answer (score 2):

I had java 7 installed on my ubuntu machine and wanted java 8. For that i followed the following steps

1. purge the older with `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*`
2. Add repository `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa`
3. Update the packages `sudo apt-get update`
4. Install java 8 with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
5. To check list of java versions installed do`sudo update-java-alternatives --list`
6. Select default java for **java** `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
7. Select default java for **javac** `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`
8. check with `java -version` and `javac -version` to check if update version is installed

I referred following link [Install OpenJDK8 on Unbuntu Trusty](https://www.geofis.org/en/install/install-on-linux/install-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-trusty/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I went to [this article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139539/make-rpm-satisfy-dependency-requirements-of-other-installed-packages), the final option did it for me:

> A final option for you to consider is `yum remove libpcap`, see how many packages it wants to remove (`yum` won't actually remove anything until you hit the Y button and press enter), since you may be able to remove these packages and use yum, if it turns out you couldn't after all, you can roll back with `yum history undo` command (I don't remember in what version of yum this was implemented in yum, so check first if this sub command is available to you). Also, make sure that you got your repositories pointing to the repos which has these files available.

After that I could remove my old jdk with:

```
sudo rpm -e java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.352.b08-2.el7_9
```